# feature list out and throw it into the foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

My requirement is that I must have everything in my list display on the page.

The problem is that, with the code I have, it only displays one thing no matter what it is !

Therefore, I would like to know what is going wrong since it does not show more than a thing forward?

**default.aspx.cs**

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
List<ForslagOpslag> forslagopslag = db.ForslagOpslags.ToList();
foreach (ForslagOpslag item in forslagopslag)
{
   //udskriver tekst på siden.
   LabelText.Text = item.text;
}
```

**Default.aspx**

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelText" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

It displays only one FORWARD, it does not display the rest.

**EIDT:**

**Default.aspx / html**

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelBrugernavn" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Literal ID="LiteralLikesOpslag" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
<asp:Literal ID="LiteralDelete" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
<div style="margin-bottom: 5px; clear: both;"></div>
<asp:Label ID="LabelText" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<div style="margin-top: 5px; clear: both;"></div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <hr class="tall" style="margin:7px 0;">
</div>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
    List<ForslagOpslag> forslagopslag = db.ForslagOpslags.ToList();
    foreach (ForslagOpslag item in forslagopslag)
    {
        //find ud af likes til forslaget.
        var likesFjern = db.ForslagOpslagLikes.Where(a => a.fk_brugerid == Helper.ReturnBrugerId()).Count();

        //udskriver fornavn og efternavn
        LabelBrugernavn.Text = item.brugere.fornavn + " " + item.brugere.efternavn;

        //udskriver tekst på siden.
        LabelText.Text = item.text;

        //finder ud af om man har synes godt om forslag før.
        if (likesFjern >= 1)
        {
            LiteralLikesOpslag.Text = "<a href='fjernsynesgodtom.aspx?id=" + item.Id + "&brugerid=" + Helper.ReturnBrugerId() + "' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Fjern synes godt om</a>";
        }
        else if (item.brugere.Id != Helper.ReturnBrugerId())
        {
            LiteralLikesOpslag.Text = "<a href='SynesGodtOm.aspx?id=" + item.Id + "' class='btn btn-success btn-xs'>Like opslag - " + item.ForslagOpslagLikes.Count() + " synes godt om</a>";
        }
        else
        {
            LiteralLikesOpslag.Text = "<p class='label label-lg label-success'>" + item.ForslagOpslagLikes.Count() + " synes godt om</p>";
        }

        //slet opslag både admin og brugeren selv.
        //giver det muligt for admin at kunne slette opslag.
        if ((item.fk_brugerid == Helper.ReturnBrugerId() || Helper.BrugerRank(Helper.ReturnBrugerId()) == 1))
        {
            LiteralDelete.Text = "<a href='slet.aspx?id=" + item.Id + "' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Slet</a>";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are always resetting the text of the label so effectively, only the last item is shown.

If you want to display all the items, you need to concatinate them.

```
   foreach (ForslagOpslag item in forslagopslag)
    {
        //udskriver tekst på siden.
        LabelText.Text += item.text;
    }
```

Notice the plus sign, to concatinate the strings.

UPDATE, to render an unordered list:

```
string list = "<ul>";

foreach (ForslagOpslag item in forslagopslag)
{
   //udskriver tekst på siden.
   list += "<li>" + item.text + "</li>";
}

list += "</ul>";

placeholder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(list));
```

Then change your .aspx page and remove the label and add this instead:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="placeholder" />
```

Comment: It gives a little right now, but it is just upon oven at each other, I want it just like a normal list after another,

I have not only text to be out, I also have lots more.

Comment: The label control is only for displaying simple text.  If you want to render out an unordered HTML list, you need to output the HTML by yourself.

Comment: Why not?  What happens?

Comment: It does not come out in a list which I would like to have it.

Comment: You really need to be more clear if anyone is going to be able to help you.  The code I gave you will output an unordered list.  How about a screenshot which shows what happens and also how you would like it to look.

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the text with each new item, use a StringBuilder to create a the longer string, or an itemrepeater so that you can display more than one item at once

So, with a StringBuilder, you could do it as such:

```
StringBuilder allText = new StringBuilder();
foreach (ForslagOpslag item in forslagopslag) {
     allText.AppendLine(item.text);
}
LabelText.Text = allText.ToString();
```

or you could use another control like an Repeater to display the full dataset at once, with a template, for example as such:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="itemRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div><asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("text")%>' /></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and in your code behind, you could add it to the page load event, as such:

```
itemRepeater.DataSource = forslagopslag;
itemRepeater.DataBind();
```

This also allows you to bind to multiple elements, or to define a header template or, just look into the [Repeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN help page